# conformal mapping of exterior region and Osgood-Taylor-Caratheodory theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[Osgood-Taylor-Caratheodory theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping))
deals with extending continuously a conformal mapping between **interior** domains of Jordan curves in $\mathbb{C}$ to the boundary(see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1913-014-02/S0002-9947-1913-1500947-9/S0002-9947-1913-1500947-9.pdf) for an original proof).

I'd like to know how to show that the theorem also holds for
**exterior** regions. Namely,

> Suppose $D$ is a bounded simply connected region in $\mathbb{C}$
>   whose boundary $\partial D$ is a Jordan curve,
>   and let $f$ be a conformal mapping from exterior of $\bar{D}$ to exterior of the closure of unit disk with $f(\infty)=\infty$,
>   then $f$ can be extended continuously to a bijective map from $\mathbb{C}\backslash D$ to $\{z:|z|\geq 1\}$.

Several papers mentioned the above assertion without any reference or proof, but I cannot find any proof.
I'm not sure if we are allowed to work in $\mathbb{\bar{C}}$.

Though there are numerous papers on conformal mapping related to closed curves(boundaries), few results can be found concerning open curves. Formally,

> Suppose $\gamma$ is a smooth($C^\infty$) bounded Jordan arc in $\mathbb{C}$, does there exist a bijective conformal mapping from  $\mathbb{C}\backslash \gamma$ to $\mathbb{C}\backslash [-1,1]$ ? If so, assume $\gamma$ is parametrized by a smooth function $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$, how to compute the conformal mapping ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling  For first box, what is the conformal mapping you find to map exterior of $\bar{D}$ to its interior ? For second box, as mentioned in the post, I did not give affirmative claim/assumption to work in $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$, and $\mathbb{C}\backslash \gamma$ is not simply connected.

Comment: If $\mathbb C_{\infty}\setminus\gamma_j$, $j=1,2$, are conformally equivalent, then so are $\mathbb C\setminus\gamma_j$ because the conformal map can send $\infty\mapsto\infty$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Suppose $\phi$ is the conformal mapping from $\mathbb{C}\backslash [-1,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}\backslash \gamma$ with continuous extension $\bar{\phi}$(result from first box). Then from Morera's theorem and continuity of $\bar{\phi}$, $\bar{\phi}$ is entire. Thus $\gamma$ is an analytic curve. This implies that any bounded Jordan arc is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$. A contradiction.

Comment: I see two questions here. Please ask separately. The first one is answered by applying a Möbius transformation to make the relevant regions bounded.